# AJAX modal dialog, fire onload if referer == <whatever>

Tags: ajax, popup, modal-dialog, http-referer

I'm trying to change my index.html to show a modal window if the referer to my site ==  (eg, if they come from Google, show a "Welcome Googler" dialog box with an image inside of it).

I'm using FancyBox, but I'm not married to it.

Any suggestions on how to code it?  I'm a C++ programmer -- Javascript isn't my forte, so straight examples would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This strikes me as an "Argh! Shut up! I don't want to do a survey! I don't want to watch an advert! Get out of my way and let me at the page!" barrier. I really wouldn't bother.

Comment: It's not.  It's a "download" window that allows me to track who downloaded the product and where they came from.  Without getting into an argument about why I should use cookies instead of this (just take my word for it that this is the best way to do it), this is the preferred method -- and I think it'll be preferred by the visitors, as well.

FWIW, environment is PHP/Apache.

Comment: Why do you need a model dialog to automatically identify where they came from?

Comment: Most people don't feel the need to use a model window to gather those. Most people gather them in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need a couple things: document.referrer, and jQuery UI. jQuery UI makes dialog boxes trivially easy.

You can find an in depth example from the [documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) but for the most part, this is what you are going to need:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('google.com') > -1){
        $("#my-dialog").dialog("open");
    }

    // this is the jquery code to set up the dialog box
    $(function() {
            // options would go inside the dialog() function
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});

</script>
```

Needed HTML:

```
<div id="my-dialog">
This is where things get displayed
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I set up the "#my-dialog" in the HTML?  ie, where in the HTML do I tag the "window" (in this case, an image) with "#my-dialog"?

Comment: "my-dialog" is the id tag of the div that contains the dialog

Comment: Scratch that question... I found the answer on the documentation page that you had already linked to.  Thank you!